Trouble with Playwright RunAndWaitForPageAsync / WaitForURLAsync and Chrome's "Always show full URLs"
When I use either of these lines of code, I get the same problem. It only works if the Chrome Browser setting "Always show full URLs" is ticked / on.
await page.WaitForURLAsync(url, new PageWaitForURLOptions { Timeout = 5000 });

or
    IPage myNewBrowserTab = await _context.RunAndWaitForPageAsync(async () =>
    {
        //Click "Launch" and set the myNewBrowserTab . 
        await page.GetByTestId("pw-Launch3rdPartyApp-launch-btn-2").GetByText("LAUNCH").ClickAsync();
    });

In both cases, I have to MANUALLY right click on the browser url and set "Always show full URLs" to be on. The problem is that this setting is off, every time I run my Playwright tests.
The above code is c# but the browser setting will be the same for java.
Does anyone know how I can ensure the "Always show full URLs" setting is on for every test OR tell it to always ignore the missing "https://"?
